# how can i write code to lerp between three colors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need to lerp betweeen 3 colors based on a number range 0 - 1.
how is this done? I'm coding in javascript.
my idea but i don't know how to implement: a conditional and a clamp between 0.0 - 0.5, 0.5 - 1.0?

This is what i have now:

```
if(s <= 0.5){
    renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorEnd,colorStart, s);    
}
else if(s>0.5){  
    renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorEnd,colorStart, s); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a place where people will do all the work for you. [See here for guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how you should ask questions, and what kind of questions are acceptable. In this case, you should try something and show us what code you have so far. This will help identify a more specific problem that we can then help you with

Comment: this is what i have now.
if(s <= 0.5){  
 renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorEnd,colorStart, s);  
 
 }else if(s>0.5){  
  renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorEnd,colorStart, s);
  
 }

Answer (score 1):

the Gradient is what you need > http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Gradient.html

the page already provides a good explanation.

you can even lerp more than 3 colors :)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.. i'm new to unity so i'm learning a lot in a very short time. cheers!

Comment: Yes, Gradient was added on Unity 4.0

Answer (score 1):

To start you out here is a Tween function that Lerps a single value over time. 
You can use it on each value of the color component. Im sure there are more efficient ways of doing it though.

```
public static float TweenValue (float from,float to,float time)
{
    if (from != to) 
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(to-from) > 1.0)
        {
            from = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, time*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else 
        {
            from = to;
        }       
    }

    return from;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing would work fine as well, you simply need to scale up the variable 's' in your code since you want each color.Lerp to utilize a value between 0 and 1.

So if you were to build a simple version of what Gradient does it would look like what you have but apply a scale remapping to your 's' value.

primarily, in each If statement (or ideally as a function call from the If statement) you would reScale your 's' to be a value between 0 and 1.

So if 's' is supposed to be `<= 0.5` (as in your first If statement) then you know that 's' would be between 0 and 0.5. 
Simply multiplying by 2 would give you a value between 0 and 1, and the color.Lerp function would work properly.

```
if(s <= 0.5){
    s *= 2f;
    renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorEnd,colorStart, s);    
}
```

But you have to be a bit more Mathy for the later.

If 's' is going to be between 0.5 and 1, you need to re-map the scale the manual way.

The math formula is:
`Y = (((X - x1) * (y2 - y1)) / (x2 - x1)) + y1`

So for your 's' that would look like:
`newS =  (((s - sMin) * (newMax - newMn)) / (sMax - sMin)) + newMin;`

Your script would look more like this:

```
//declare variables somewhere before If statements:

color color1, color2, color3;

float newS, sMin, sMax, newMin = 0, newMax = 1;


//your If statements. you can always add more if you want more color ranges.


if(s >= 0 && <= 0.5){
    sMin = 0;
    sMax = 0.5;
    newS =  (((s - sMin) * (newMax - newMn)) / (sMax - sMin)) + newMin;
    renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(color2,color1, newS);    
}

else if(s>0.5 && s<=1){
    sMin = 0.5;
    sMax = 1;
    newS =  (((s - sMin) * (newMax - newMn)) / (sMax - sMin)) + newMin;
    renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(color3,color2, newS); 
}
```